# Useful site for searching popular rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

I was used to use acts_as_paranoid for logical deletion.  But it doesn't support latest rails version.  I want to search popular plugin for it.  And not only for logical deletion, for user authentication (Devise), file upload (paperclip) and so on.

Does anyone know the useful site for searching popular rails plugin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's what you are looking for https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/

Comment: It's what I want.  Thank you!!